# Printing Ascii symbols

Tags: c, ascii

I'm trying to print Ascii symbols like a heart. The ASCII representation of this is 03, but I don't know how to implement that in my code.

```
int main(void)
{
printf("Heart: %c", 03); //
return 0;
}
```

I get an upside down question mark..
How do I use it?

Comment: 03 in ASCII is a control character for ETX (End of Text)...

Comment: So how do I print the little heart symbol? What would my statement look like? That's what I'm struggling with.

Comment: There *is* no heart symbol in ASCII. You might want Unicode.

Comment: BTW: `03` is 3 in octal.  Suggest avoiding the leading `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol that will display depends on the operating system on which you're running this code, and potentially (again depending on OS) the code page that is currently selected.

The heart was something that MS-DOS added to [code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) as a representation of that unprintable control character.

[ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) does not define a print representation of ASCII value 3.

If you are on a system that will display Unicode characters, you might try "\u2764" ❤

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2764/index.htm